# How to Receive Federal Refund Using TurboTax

Tags: united-states, taxes, refund, turbotax

In TurboTax, there are two options to receive your refund as show in the below screenshot:

[image]

I am not sure which option to choose. I have never used CreditKarma before. If I choose the first option, would I have to set up a CreditKarma account? Also could I potentially get more than the what I would get using the second option?

Or is the second option the safest bet?

Answer (score 6):

CreditKarma is an Intuit product that, among other things, offers a high-yield savings account.

They are, essentially, promoting another of their products within the one you're using. Note the footnotes 1-4 (which aren't in your screenshot).

You would need to create a CK account if you don't have one, you'd essentially be opening a savings account with them.  Whether or not this is a good idea depends entirely on where you're at in terms of building savings. If you want the money for immediate use, go direct deposit. If you're building savings and want to try to score some free money and don't mind opening another savings account to do so, then give the fine print a read-through, make sure they're insured, etc, etc.

Personally, I just go direct deposit and carry on with my savings plan, but that has as much to do with "I just did my taxes and don't want to read paperwork to open a new account somewhere else" as anything else.

Comment: Thanks. Also if it asks for your AGI (adjusted gross income) from 2019, what if it blank on the previous return? Should I just put $0?

Comment: They ask that because it's how the IRS makes sure they're matching your return up correctly with the rest of your file. If you had zero AGI last year, then yes. If you had a non-zero AGI and can find it, I'd put that in. But that sounds like a system error and beyond the scope of the question. That's one I'd ask their tech support about, instead.

Answer (score 2):

You not only have to create a CreditKarma account to receive the tax refund, but if you want to receive the $50 bonus and to be eligible for entering the $50K sweepstakes, you also need to arrange for direct deposit of your paycheck into the new CreditKarma account. So, Yes, you *could* get an extra $50 bonus over and above what your regular bank account will receive, but you will need to are-arrange your financial life a little because now your paycheck is being deposited into your CreditKarma account, whereas you are presumably set up for paying credit-card and utility bills from your regular checking account. So, set up a regular transfer of money from your new CreditKarma account, or switch over all your bill payments to the new CreditKarma account. And what about debit cards and cash withdrawals if needed?